# How to parallelize method for creating a List and track each element position/index in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a method which creates 1000 surfaces in a loop and store them in the list:

```
List<Surface> surfaces = new List<Surface>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    Surface surface = builder.buildSurface(int length, int width, new Position (x, y, z);
    surfaces.Add(surface);
    x +=2; y+= 4, z++;    // each surface is shifted every iteration
}
```

When all surfaces were generated, I can output them in any specific order, for example in matrix form A[i][j].

How can I parallelize creation of surfaces and track position/index? I think each surface creation can be executed in parallel, but I want to know it's index for output according to surface position.

Is it possible to create a TheadPool  which will generate 1000 surfaces in parallel and store them in ConcurrentDictionary<index, Surface>() so I can output them in a specific order?

P.S. I tried to split the method in half with Parallel.Invoke:

```
 Parallel.Invoke(
                  () => builder.buildLeft(),
                  () => builder.buildRight());
```

So the execution time reduced almost 2 times, but I want to utilize all cores of CPU for such time consuming task.

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) or [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop). However you would have to prepare your `x`, `y` and `z` values somehow

Comment: Parallel.For will work, but it generates surfaces in random sequence, while I'm changing Position(x,y,z) gradually with each iteration from 0 to 1000.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PLINQ (parallel linq) as foolowing

```
var surfaces = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0,1000)
                    .AsOrdered()
                    .Select(i=>builder.buildSurface(
                            length, width,
                            new Position (i*2, i*4, i)))
                    .ToList();
```

This sample assumes that `x, y, z` values are connected with item index `i` as `x=i*2, y=i*4, z=i`. If you need some different approach of calculation of `x, y, z` then you may need to prepare collection with such a data separately before calling PLINQ.

Please note `AsOrdered()` call above - it tells PLINQ to preserve order when building output list, but this preserving is not free. So, if you really not need exactly the `List` of items, but any storage with specified index/key is ok, you can try unordered PLINQ with `Dictionary` instead of `List`

```
 var surfaces = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0,1000)
                    .ToDictionary(i=>i, i=>builder.buildSurface(
                            length, width,
                            new Position (i*2, i*4, i)));
```

I do not know, which variant will be faster, but you can perform tests yourself before making decision.

Comment: Emphasis on the last part. PLINQ can be quite slow sometimes